# How to keep ordering when saving dict as pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have some example data as:

```
dic = {'common': {'value': 18, 'attr': 20, 'param': 22},
       'fuzzy': {'value': 14, 'attr': 21, 'param': 24},
       'adhead': {'value': 13, 'attr': 20, 'param': 29}}
```

Executing `pd.DataFrame(dic)` I get:

```
       common  fuzzy  adhead
attr       20     21      20
param      22     24      29
value      18     14      13
```

And here, 'external' columns are ok, but 'internal' are sorted, this is what I need to avoid. How to do it quick? (Need to keep ordering - here rows are sorted)

Hint: I've got a message on the colsole:

> **main**:95: FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version of pandas will change to not sort by
>   default.
>
> To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=True'.
>
> To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass
>   sort=False

but don;t know what's for. Passing this argument to `pd.DataFrame(dic, sort=False)` returns:
`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort'`.

Comment: Please refer [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: dictionaries are not ordered, so there is no order to mantain.

Comment: @ecortazar Don't you think OrderedDict would work?

Comment: Ok, but I've tried 'OrderedDict' and nothing changed.

Comment: Since the sub-dict's order seems to be important, a dictionary is clearly not the right data-structure for them. I would have recommended starting from lists. If a dictionary is what you receive, there is no way for pandas to guess what the correct order should be, so you'd need to reindex after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then using `reindex` as protection

```
pd.DataFrame(dic).reindex(index=['value','attr','param'])
Out[553]: 
       common  fuzzy  adhead
value      18     14      13
attr       20     21      20
param      22     24      29
```